# Windows 10 html5 audio volume level issue

Tags: audio, video, windows-10, youtube

I have upgraded my operating system from Win 8.1 to Win 10 few days ago and I have registered some audio level issues when I watch videos on YouTube. I set the pc's audio level to my comfort level, let's say it's 10% (level bar on YouTube player is always at 100%), but when I replay the same video, it seems that audio level is on much higher level, about 50% or higher (windows audio level bar is still at 10% but it plays very much louder. Than I reduce the audio level and it jumps to 8%. I tried to reinstall audio drivers, but it din't fix this problem. I have Asus x550v laptop and my friend who has the same model has this issue too.

Pls, any experience with this issue?

Comment: You can try [turning off adudio enhancements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-sound-problems#v1h=tab05) and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too have stumbled upon this issue recently. Not exactly sure why it started happening to me when I would watch youtube videos, but it's as you say, the volume randomly jumps up super high and then drops back down.

After toying with the 'enhancement' tweaks like everyone always recommends (but that never works for everyone that has this issue) and also shutting off my microphone, I was still getting the issue.

I finally narrowed it down to the fact that youTube uses HTML5 now as its default player. For some reason, that causes havoc, maybe with Realtek audio hardware, I'm not the sure.

The best thing you can do, and how I fixed my problem, is to **download the [Youtube Flash Video Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-video-player/) add-on for Firefox**. That adds a little icon next to your address bar that lets you set Youtube's default player to Flash. That fixed the issue for me, hope it does for you too.